# reading text with whitespaces in c++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

i'm trying to read in the following text file into different variables:

```
title
subject name
123
subject2 name
124
subject3 name
125
```

so far i've been using the following code

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("filename.txt");
......etc

myfile >> string1
while(myfile >> string2 && myfile >> int1){
    cout << "read string " << string2 << "and int " << int1 << endl;
}
```

This method doesn't seem to like the space between "subject name" and it isn't picking up so it doesn't run the while loop. Is there an easy way i can fix this?

Comment: So... you want the value from each line in a variable?

Comment: yeh each line is a different variable some are int some are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem I noticed when I looked at your code was the missing semicolon `;` after

`myfile >> string1` but this is just a syntax error.

The while loop you're trying to use will only evaluate when both conditions are true because you're using `&&` operator.

As @sftrabbit said extraction operator `>>` in C++ 
leaves a new line character `\n` in the input buffer and then when you're trying to input

```
std::getline(myfile, string2) && myfile >> int1
```

First condition `std::getline(myfile, string2)` doesn't have a problem getting a new line character and will evaluate to true, but then second condition `myfile >> int1` will evaluate to false because it will get a character(s) when it's expecting an integer. That's why your while loop doesn't want to execute.

You can easily fix this problem when you change the extraction operator in 
 `myfile >> string1` with `getline(myfile, string1);` because getline will leave an empty input buffer.

But then you will have another problem. The while loop will execute only once again because there is \n left in the input buffer so you'll need a `myfile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`.

Your final code should lool like this:

```
int main ()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    string string1;
    string string2;
    int int1;

    myfile.open("filename.txt");

    getline(myfile, string1);

    while(getline(myfile, string2) && myfile >> int1)
    {
        myfile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "read string " << string2 << " and int " << int1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: it was the first getline i was missing, this is perfect thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Extraction with `>>` into a `std::string` will read up until the next whitespace. So yes, it'll only extract a single word from the line. If you want to extract the entire line, use `std::getline`. You can incorporate it as follows:

```
while(std::getline(myfile, string2) &&
      myfile >> int1) {
    myfile.ignore();
    cout << "read string " << string2 << "and int " << int1 << endl;
}
```

The `ignore` is required because extraction into the `int` will leave the following `\n` character in the stream. This needs to be removed for the following `std::getline` in the next iteration to succeed.

Comment: @clairharrison How much output do you get?

Comment: i get a completely blank output

Comment: the exact code im running is: `ifstream myfile;

 myfile.open("text.txt");
 string string1, string2;
 int int1;

 myfile >> string1;
 cout << string1 << endl;
 while(std::getline(myfile, string2) && myfile >> int1) {
  myfile.ignore();
  cout << "read string " << string2 << "and int " << int1 << endl;
 }`

Comment: @clairharrison Did you check to see if the file opened correctly with `is_open`?

Comment: that was part of the problem, it now outputs "title" but the while loop still doesn't run

Comment: it runs if i change the second part of the while condition to read into a string rather than an int but i need it read into an int